# Why does my Makefile do nothing?

Tags: c, unix, makefile

```
#
# MakeFile assignment 2
# Variables

CC=gcc 
LINK=gcc
CFLAGS=-c -Wall -I.
OBJECT_FILES = cmpsc311-f13-assign2.o a2support.o

#Suffix rules
.SUFFIXES: .c .o

.c.o:
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $<

#Productions
cmpsc311-f13-assign2 : $(OBJECT_FILES)
    $(LINK) $(OBJECT_FILES) -o $@

#Dependencies
 cmpsc311-f13-assign2.o : cmpsc311-f13-assign2.c a2support.h
 a2support.o : a2support.c a2support.h

clean:
    rm cmpsc311-f13-assign2.o
    rm a2support.o
```

Every time I use the command `make Makefile` it does nothing, is there something wrong with my makefile or is it another issue?

Running the following command also dose nothing:

```
gcc -o cmpsc311-f13-assign2 cmpsc311-f13-assign2.c a2support.c a2support.h -I.
```

Comment: I presume you've tried running `make -d` to actually see what's happening?

Comment: I am pretty new to C programming and i just tried that command and i got a whole lot of stuff i dont understand.

Comment: I'd suggest sticking to simpler makefiles until you get more experience, then.

Answer (score 3):

> Every time I use the command `make Makefile` it does nothing

`make Makefile` tries to create `Makefile`. Since you don't have any rule to create it, there's nothing to do.

Usually `make` is invoked with no arguments; it uses `Makefile` by default, and tries to make the first target defined (in your case, `cmpsc311-f13-assign2`).

You can use the `-f` option to specify a different makefile to use:

```
make -f foo.mk
```

or you can use an argument to specify what to build:

```
make clean
```

or both:

```
make -f foo.mk clean
```

Comment: gcc  -c -c -Wall -I. -o cmpsc311-f13-assign2.o cmpsc311-f13-assign2.c
gcc  -c -c -Wall -I. -o a2support.o a2support.c
gcc cmpsc311-f13-assign2.o a2support.o -o cmpsc311-f13-assign2  is what i get now how do I run the program now

Comment: @user2803166: `./cmpsc311-f13-assign2`

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the answer mentioned above you also need to add a TAB character at line 14.

`$(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $<`

Comment: You need to specify a 'recipe' to make target 'cmpsc311-f13-assign2.o'. You've only specified the target and the prerequisites. https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Rule-Introduction